# Simple XQuery starts-with

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm learning xml stuff and can't get this simple Xquery to work.

XML:

```
<ModuleList>
<Module id="U08606">
<ModuleName>Discrete Mathematics</ModuleName>
</Module>
</ModuleList>
```

I'm trying to return the name where the attribute id starts with "U086"

XQuery:

```
for $i in doc("q1.xml")//ModuleList/Module
where starts-with($i/id, 'U086')
return $i/ModuleName
```

nothing gets returned atm, any ideas why? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are selected using the `@` symbol:

```
starts-with($i/@id, 'U086')
```